# How do i redirect pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, router

Axios post is working then page redirecting to "/order" (SiparisOnay.js) and then redirecting again to "/pizza?..." (SiparisOlustur.js) right back. How can I make "/order" page stays without directing back to "/pizza"?

App.js

```
    return (
  <StrictMode>
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Home />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/pizza" children={<SiparisOlustur />} />
      <Route path="/order" children={<SiparisOnay />} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</StrictMode>
);
```

SiparisOlustur.js

```
const handleSubmit = () => {   
    axios
        .post("https://reqres.in/api/users", JSON.stringify(siparis))
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);  
            history.push("/order");
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err.response); 
        }); 

    console.log(siparis);
};
```

SiparisOnay.js

```
return (
    <header>
        <h1>Teknolojik Yemekler</h1>
        <span className='tebrikler-mesaj'>TEBRIKLER!<br />SİPARİŞİNİZ ALINDI!</span>
    </header>
);
```